# Why is there an inconsistency between manual calculations result and R calculation result in t-test?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Initially, I asked this question in "Cross Validated" but since no clear answer was received I moved the question to here.

I have the following sample:

`tree length : 186, 181, 176, 149, 184, 190, 158, 139, 175, 148, 152, 111`

after using some nutrient:

`tree length : 181, 191, 186, 129, 178, 194, 139, 122, 195, 158, 158, 104`

I am using Welch two sample t-test with two-tailed testing to see if the nutrient had an effect on tree growth therefore,

$H_0$: Nutrient had no effect.

$H_1$: Nutrient had an effect.

The results in R are as follows:

```
l1 = c(186, 181, 176, 149, 184, 190, 158, 139, 175, 148, 152, 111)
summary(l1); length(l1);  sd(l1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  111.0   148.8   166.5   162.4   181.8   190.0 
[1] 12
[1] 23.70063

l2 = c(181, 191, 186, 129, 178, 194, 139, 122, 195, 158, 158, 104)
summary(l2); length(l2);  sd(l2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  104.0   136.5   168.0   161.2   187.2   195.0 
[1] 12
[1] 31.26754

t.test(l1, l2, alternative = c("two.sided"), paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  l1 and l2
t = 0.10301, df = 20.503, p-value = 0.919
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -22.42215  24.75548
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 162.4167  161.2500
```

Based on the results, $H_0$ is rejected as there has been an effect.

Now, I do the calculations manually:

$t_\alpha = \frac{\mu_1 - \mu_2}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1} + \frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}}} = \frac{162.4 - 161.2}{\sqrt{ \frac{23.7^2}{12} + \frac{31.268^2}{12}}} \approx 0.11$

I get the t-value to be 0.11 where there is a 0.01 difference between this result and the R's one (probably due to the different degree of freedom? R uses 20.503 whereas I am using 22 in my calculations). Then based on the significance level of 0.05 and degree of freedom 22, I find the critical value to be 2.074 in the t-distribution table. So since 0.11 < 2.074 $\Rightarrow t_\alpha$ < critical-value, the null hypothesis is failed to reject. But this is inconsistence with R result as in R the null hypothesis was rejected and alternative hypothesis was supported: `alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0`. So why is there an inconsistency between R result and manual calculation result?

Comment: Your data are **paired**: two values for tree 1, two values for tree 2, etc. So you should use paired=TRUE in t.test and change your manual calculation accordingly.

Comment: @awkward Thanks. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three issues:

- Neither your manual calculation nor the R automated calculation reject the null hypothesis, and you can see this from the high $p$-value and the confidence interval overlapping $0$.  The critical value from $R$ would be `qt(0.975,20.503)` i.e. about $2.083$, much larger than its $t \approx 0.103$ and  not far from your critical value of $2.074$
- rounding of the means: $162.4-161.2=1.2$ but $162.4167 - 161.2500 = 1.1667$; this can make the $t$-value about $0.106$ (rounding to $0.11$) rather than $0.103$
- the number of degrees of freedom: when [Welch's $t$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test) is used when the two variances are not assumed to be equal, there is the complicated expression below for approximating the degrees of freedom (usually not an integer) so your $\nu=(12-1)+(12-1) =22$ would be based  on an assumption the variances are equal while removing this assumptions gives about $20.5$. $$\nu \quad  \approx \quad
  {\dfrac{\left( \; {s_1^2 \over n_1} \; + \; {s_2^2 \over n_2} \; \right)^2 } 
   { \quad {s_1^4 \over n_1^2 (n_1-1)} \; + \; {s_2^4 \over n_2^2 (n_2-1) } \quad }}$$

Comment: Regarding the first bullet point in your answer, when in R outcome it is stated: `alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0`, doesn't this statement confirms that there is a difference in the means and hence $H_0$ is rejected and $H_1$ is accepted?

Comment: @Coder - no, I do not think so.  It is just telling you that the alternative hypothesis is $H_1: \mu_1 \not =\mu_2$ because you explicitly or implicitly chose `"two.sided"` though this would be more useful if for example you had chosen `"greater"` and then forgotten which way round this meant.  If you tried `t.test(l2,l2)` then it would say the same thing even though there is clearly no empirical difference in means between a set of sample data and itself.

Comment: Thank you, this is what had made me confused. Your answer was very clear and helpful.